# CSS dropdown menu z-index

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do a dropdown menu that I designed with photoshop. However, there is a border in the top of this menu. The image, can explain it better:

[image: The menu I need to do]

Using CSS, all I get is a line that covers more that it is designed to. I tryed to use z-index position to make, but without success. Take a look at my code:

```
nav{

    display: inline;
    font-weight:900;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size:13px;
    margin-left:95px;
}
.menu > li > a {

    width:auto;
    padding:10px 20px 10px 10px;
    background-image:url('img/seta_menu.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:right 50%;
}

.menu>li{   

    width:auto;
    margin-right:45px;
    padding:10px;
    border-left: solid 1px #F8FAFA;
    border-right: solid 1px #F8FAFA;
    border-top:solid 1px #F8FAFA;
    border-bottom:solid 1px #F8FAFA;
}

.menu>li:hover{

    border-left: solid 1px #bdc9c5;
    border-right: solid 1px #bdc9c5;
    border-top:solid 1px #bdc9c5;
    border-bottom:solid 1px #bdc9c5;
    background-color:white;

}

nav>div{

    display:inline; 

}
nav>div>ul{

    display: inline;

}
.menu li{
    display: inline-table;
}
.menu>li:hover >ul{

    display:block;

}
.sub-menu{

    position:absolute;  
    display:none;
    padding:10px;
    margin-left:-11px;
    margin-top:10px;
    border-left: solid 1px #bdc9c5;
    border-right: solid 1px #bdc9c5;
    border-bottom:solid 1px #bdc9c5;
    /*border-top:solid 1px #bdc9c5;*/
    background-color:white; 

}

.sub-menu ol, ul {

    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;

}
.sub-menu > li{

    display:block;

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/btgfE/

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved...

**jsfiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/btgfE/2/

1) uncomment the top border of the `.sub-menu`

2) comment out the bottom border of the `.menu>li:hover`

3) give `.sub-menu` the css rule `z-index:-1;`

4) decrease the `margin-top` of `.sub-menu` to `9px`

Really what this is doing is letting the top level menu item slightly overlap ontop of the sub-menu item's top border, giving the appearance you are looking for

Comment: When I put the z-index:-1, the div container is getting over the submenu. Look: http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/02912c7sa9 –
What can I do with this div? I tryed z-index:-2 without success

Comment: try giving your .menu class z-index:100; if this doesn't solve your problem you will have to provide an updated jsfiddle that shows the problem

Comment: Ok, I'm trying somethings here and I will update what I get here

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/btgfE/4/

I gave the `.submenu` a `z-index` of -1, this fixed it.

I also changed the colours so they are more easily visible. You will want to set the green to white, I did this so that you can see the border is on top of the sub-menu's border

Comment: But the problem is the submenu top border. Look: <img src="http://s1.postimage.org/t92d3uadb/Untitled_1.png"/>